# iOS having a 'detail' bar available at all times

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, prompt

I would like to have a small view about the size of a toolbar available at the top of my app at anytime. This view would be available only for displaying some textual details. I was thinking of setting the root view controller to be a navigation controller and setting the prompt to be what I want to display, but this seems kind of hacky. Does anyone have any other ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I do it is to add a `UIView` to the `UIWindow` of the application delegate. For example, you can go to `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and `[self.window addSubview:overlay];` where overlay is a `UIView` created programmatically or in IB.

Comment: This seems to work except that the second view that I am adding does not seem to rotate properly. Maybe, I should be adding it as a view controller instead of just a view in the window?